# Class chaining methods (CakePHP 3.x | Components)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, method-chaining

I'm having problems, when trying to chain more than 3 methods in a row.
Below, i will show You my component code:

```
if ($this->UserPayments->save($_payment) instanceof UserPayment) {
           $this->loadComponent('LiqPay');

           $this->LiqPay
                ->_setPublicKey(Configure::read('LiqPay.public_key'))
                ->_setPrivateKey(Configure::read('LiqPay.private_key'))
                ->_setOrderId($_payment->id);

           $this->LiqPay
                ->_setDescription(__(
                        'payment',
                        "{$this->_user['first_name']} {$this->_user['last_name']}",
                        $_payment->amount))
                ->_setCurrency('eur')
                ->_setAmount($_payment->amount);

          $this->LiqPay
                ->_setActionType('pay');

          return $this->_jsonResponse($this->LiqPay->_getConfig());
  }
```

I have no idea, how to allow chainings more than 3 level.
Any ideas?

Comment: What problems are you talking about? Your question doesn't contain any actual problem description, also it doesn't show the actual component code, only the code that makes use of the component, so people wil have a hard time figuring out what's happening there.

Comment: @ndm, read last line of question.

Comment: I've seent it, however "having no idea" is not a problem description - there are no rules that need to be followed in order to be able to chain more than three method calls. A proper problem description would be to explain what exactly happens when you chain more that three calls, and what should happen instead, garnished with the source code of the involved methods.